# How to use case-insensitive match in MERGE clause?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, case-insensitive

I have a question as specified in the title. For example, here is my current query:

```
MERGE (n:Person { name: 'John' })
ON CREATE SET n.age = 30
ON MATCH SET n.age = 30
```

I want to have a case-insensitive search. So, the `name` maybe `john, JOHN, joHN`, doesn't matter, it should still match.

As far as I know, we can achieve case-insensitive search by using regular expression in the `WHERE` clause. For example:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.name =~ '(?i)John'
```

However, `MERGE` clause doesn't support `WHERE` clause. It would be **invalid** to say:

```
MERGE (n:Person)
WHERE n.name =~ '(?i)John'
ON CREATE SET n.age = 30
ON MATCH SET n.age = 30
```

So, **what is the solution in this case?** One suggestion I found uses `OPTIONAL MATCH`. The query will be:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i)John'
WITH n
WHERE n IS NOT NULL SET n.age = 30

OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i)John'
WITH n
WHERE n IS NULL MERGE (n:Person { name: 'John', age: 30 })
```

What do you think about this solution? Do you have any suggestion? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

**Option 1.**

If it is OK to add a new property to each `Person` node that contains the name in a consistent case (say, uppercase), there is a workaround.

The workaround would require that you first add the new property to all `Person` nodes. For example:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
SET p.uName = TOUPPER(p.name);
```

After the new property is added, you can use `MERGE` directly. *In the following query, I assume that the age and the name you are looking for are passed to the query as the [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/) `$age` and `$name`*.

```
MERGE (p:Person {uName: TOUPPER($name)})
ON CREATE SET p.name = $name
SET p.age = $age;
```

This query sets the `name` property if the node was just created. Also, since you always want to set the age, this query always does that.

**Option 2.**

If you do not want to add a new property, you can use the APOC procedure [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_when_procedures) to optionally create the `Person` node and get back the optionally created node (or the existing node) to do further processing on it. For example:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.name =~ ('(?i)' + $name)
CALL apoc.do.when(
  n IS NULL,
  'CREATE (p:Person {name: $name}) RETURN p',
  'RETURN $existing AS p',
  {name:$name, existing: n}) YIELD value
WITH value.p AS p
SET p.age = $age
RETURN p;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought about this (sorry, I forgot to mention). But this solution requires additional storage. Since my database is quite large, I would prefer to avoid this. Is there any way that we only have to play with Cypher?

Comment: That is interesting! I will try it. Thank you :)